# How to keep znode and its backup's data consistency with zookeeper

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing

When I use zookeeper to build java application, a worker znode records key/value from client in memory . A worker has a backup znode. after the worker node fails, the backup node replace him. How to keep the main node and backup node's recorded key/value exactly the same?
Maybe I can make client send every request to both of them. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't get your question. AFAIR nodes in zookeeper cluster are exact copies and each of them keeps whole data in memory. Whenever one node fails cluster still runs (assuming that majority of the nodes is still up). If the leader fail new leader is elected, but still cluster is operational.

Comment: Check https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches 
You could create a simple program to set a data watch on the worker znode and whenever an event arrives, setData on the backup node and re-enable a data znode for the worker one. However, you should understand that znodes do not fail but ZooKeeper servers do and for that scenario it is suggested to use multiple ZooKeeper servers to form a reliable cluster. Check the Admin's guide https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperAdmin.html